Is it inappropriate to make your question less "searchable"?
I want to make my Worldbuilding.SE questions less searchable by genericizing or removing key terms within such as specific names and titles.
Out on a whim, I searched one of my specific worldbuilding-related names and my Worldbuilding.SE questions popped up immediately. For personal reasons, this deeply unsettles me. I want to correct this by mass-editing my questions to be more 'generic' and less traceable to me.
By Stack Exchange etiquette, is it inappropriate to reduce my questions' searchability?

Can you define what you mean by "less searchable"? Are you trying to make the questions not show up for any search terms (or as many as possible), or are you trying to make the questions less easy to specifically track by generalising them and removing terms and names that stand out?

@VLAZ Preferably the former but my options are tied so the latter

What problem are you trying to solve? Are you simply trying to hid the details of your creativity? You should have read the terms of service before using the site my friend. You should read the terms of service on every site before using that site.

@JBH Pretty much, yes. I'm trying to assess how well that would fly here. (And I would have read the terms of service if a certain force didn't influence me.)

I've rolled my eyes for years at people who came here expecting to hide the crown jewels and nevertheless expecting us to pony up all our best ideas. Do unto others my friend....

@JBH You're right. It would be very hypocritical of me.

@Dmyt --- Can you clarify something for me please? When you say you want to generalise by removing "specific names and titles", and when you did this search on a whim, did you happen to google up a term like "chthonic hivemind" or some other highly specific term that could lead someone to identify you outside of WB.SE? Now that we've got staff involvement, I want to make sure we're crystal clear on what you actually intend to ask!

@elemtilas Actually, yes. That's exactly how I did it.

Thanks Dmyt. So the question seems clearer to me: you're not trying to obfuscate search results or undermine search results in general. You're trying to basically protect your own identity.

As confirmed by a Community Manager in comment:

This is essentially correct. I'm not going to (personally) require communities to take this stance, but let's say I would be very surprised if a SE community took a contrary position. Dissociation is the canonical tool for removing your name from content - not alteration of that content: discoverability is the point.

Stackexchange is meant to be a repository of answers and questions.
I would say that making the questions less searchable goes against that.
Also don't forget that once posted, content does not belong to you, but to Stackexchange and the community.
You can however request the posts to be disassociated from your profile. More info here.

It's possible OP meant "less searchable" as in "less identifiable". Rather than making the core question deliberately hard to find. The difference between "How would MyCustomEmpire deal with the Renaissance" vs "How would an empire  deal with the Renaissance". The latter is less likely to be found if searching for MyCustomEmpire. But still findable by people looking for empires and Renaissance.

There is no transfer of copyright when a question or an answer is posted on Stack Exchange. The author retains full rights; all they do is grant a certain license to Stack Exchange, and a different license to the all and sundry readers. The "community", whatever that may be, does not get any special rights. The author only grants a license to SE,  as described in the ToS, and the rights specified by the Creative Commons Share Alike license to the general public.

@AlexP Thanks, that was my understanding as well but I had been on hiatus for a while there.

@AlexP The issue is not as simple as you suggest.

This is essentially correct. I'm not going to (personally) require communities to take this stance, but let's say I would be very surprised if a SE community took a contrary position. Dissociation is the canonical tool for removing your name from content - not alteration of that content: discoverability is the point.

No.

SE, to my knowledge, has no rule and WB.SE has no policy governing the use of specific worldbuilding-related names. Although I can't allay your unsettlement, I can at least encourage you to make sufficient edits so that there is less reason for you to be concerned.

I would note, however, that even if you edit your questions, that doesn't make the originals go away. I suspect that if someone really wanted to dig, they could probably find. I'd also note the miniscule likelihood that some random person with no knowledge of either you, this forum or chthonic hiveminds in general is going to actually hit the google lottery. In other words, "feeling unsettled" is one thing and "having an objective rationale" is another. While we're not gathered to discuss your inner life, my only question here would be which are you actually dealing with.

"I suspect that if someone really wanted to dig, they could probably find" to expand on this - essentially, once you post something on a public site on the Internet (private spaces are not guaranteed to be private, either), consider that the cat is out of the bag. For SE, specifically, all edits are publicly visible - there is a link under the post that shows the revision history. Here is how one revision history looks like of a post I editet twice. You can see all three (initia, edit #1, edit #2) versions. Mods can

redact away old revisions but usually if there is a sensitive information like a password, you can consider it leaked. Still, if you did something like accidentally add personal information, edited it away, then you can probably flag for a redaction. Outside of direct site tools, there is the Web Archive - it keeps copies of a lot of pages on the Internet. The intent is benign - pages can go down and it is good to have some copy of the information. It might happen that they took a snapshot of a page with exposed private information, though.

Many users might run something similar but on a smaller scale. I'm subscribed to the RSS feed for new questions, for example. I find it easier to look at content (I'm subscribed to several RSS feeds, so I can look at them centrally). However, if somebody posts a question and deletes it, then I'd still be able to see it if the feed reader picked it up.

I'll finish with a quote from this infinitely quotable article: "Here are the secret rules of the internet: five minutes after you open a web browser for the first time, a kid in Russia has your social security number. Did you sign up for something? A computer at the NSA now automatically tracks your physical location for the rest of your life. Sent an email? Your email address just went up on a billboard in Nigeria." Context is slightly different but the quote is still applicable here.

See comment from a Community Manager to my answer.

@L.Dutch --- Yes, I see that. I don't actually disagree with what you're saying in your answer, but I do believe that you're not answering the question. This isn't a question of generally hiding a SE question from search engines. This is a question of making one's personal identity less discoverable in spite of having written questions on SE.

@elemtilas, again, see above: making one's personal identity less discoverable in spite of having written questions on SE = disassociate the post from the profile posting it

@L.Dutch --- See Dmyt's comment. I asked for clarification. They're talking about specific terms within the question. E.g. "hivemind". Dissociation will not help with that. Dissociation seems to be a rather radical approach.
